# Singleton Not Instantiating Correctly

Tags: objective-c, xcode, singleton

I'm playing around with idea of singleton cache. The setup is quite simple:

In my singleton class, I am instantiating one instance as follows:

```
+(SharedInstanceTest*)sharedInstace
{
    static SharedInstanceTest *sharedInstace=nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstace=[[SharedInstanceTest alloc]init];
    });
    NSLog(@"Share Instance Allocated");

    return sharedInstace;
}


+(id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    return [self sharedInstace];
}
```

Now in the rootViewController, I am calling the sharedInstance just so that I can see the NSLog to make sure it has been instantiated.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [SharedInstanceTest sharedInstace];

}
```

I get no NSLog. Any idea why?

Comment: Don't override allocWithZone - does that make a difference?

Comment: that was it, strange I got that approach from big nerd book... add ur answer I'll mark it as correct

Comment: any idea why by the way?

Comment: My guess is a loop - do you know if you ever returned out of that function?  `alloc` may internally call `allocWithZone` but I don't know.  Docs say `Do not override allocWithZone: to include any initialization code. Instead, class-specific versions of init... methods.` http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: no it didn't return actually, the idea was that alloc calls allocWithZone so if you want to force people to use a singleton, you add that code to allocWithZone. That was the bnr suggestion...

Comment: I guess I could just raise an exception telling people to use sharedInstance in alloc

Comment: No you don't want to do that.  Definitely don't throw exceptions in alloc - otherwise your do_once block will fail.  I think if you document that's the best you can do.  Objective-C lets you pass messages to "private" methods too, so it becomes a chore to really hide things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not override `allocWithZone`.  It is probably causing a loop or something when you do `[SharedInstanceTest alloc]`.

Comment: Overriding `allocWithZone:` is okay; you just can't then use `alloc` to create the instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `allocWithZone:` in order to prevent clients from creating more instances. You just can't use `alloc` to create the shared instance, because that will end up calling `allocWithZone:`; then you have an infinite loop, as SB. answered.

You can do something like this (to convert to ARC, just remove the `retain` in `allocWithZone:`):

```
#import "MySingleton.h"

static MySingleton * defaultMySingleton = nil;

//MySingleton * defaultMySingleton = nil;
//void initialize_defaultMySingleton(void) {
//    [MySingleton defaultMySingleton];
//}

@implementation MySingleton

+ (MySingleton *)defaultMySingleton {

    // Create the instance if it has not been already.
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        // Call super's implementation because allocWithZone: is overridden
        // to call defaultMySingleton
        // The class owns this instance.
        defaultMySingleton = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
    });

    return defaultMySingleton;
}

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    // Users of alloc, although they shouldn't be using this,
    // will expect a +1 retain count. Bump it to allow for eventual release.
    return [[self defaultMySingleton] retain];
}

- (id)init
{
    // If defaultMySingleton exists, then it is self here. Just return it.
    if( defaultMySingleton ) return defaultMySingleton;

    // Otherwise, do normal setup.
    self = [super init];
    if( !self ) return nil;

    return self;
}

@end
```

This was inspired by [Peter Hosey's singleton blog post](http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2009-06-17/doing-it-wrong), though he seems to have changed his implementation quite a bit since I last read it.